# About the contraction

Tags: exterior-algebra

How can I prove that if  $V$ is a vector space, $v\in V$ and if $T\in\wedge^k V^*$ and $S\in\wedge^l V^*$ then $i(v)(T\wedge S)=i(v)T\wedge S+(-1)^k T\wedge(i(v)S)$. Thanks